# phonegap 5.1.1 fail build Android: processDebugManifest

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build a project with phone gap 5.1.1 on mac yosemite, but when I run the CLI "phone gap build android" its give me BUILD FAILED with this error: processDebugManifest.

I've set the environment variable like this:

> ANDROID_HOME=“/Users/andrea/android-sdk-macosx”  export
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
>   export ANT_HOME=/Users/andrea/ant  export
>   PATH=${PATH}:/Users/andrea/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/andrea/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/andrea/ant/bin

And I've installed git, node too. 
I don't understand why the build fail, I've always did this way 
Can you help me?

Comment: It's a bug on phonegap 5.1.1, it will be fixed on the next release. You can put this on the config.xml to make it build <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />

Comment: but doesn't the build resets the config? @jcesarmobile

Comment: It reset the config.xml on platforms/android/res/xml, you have to put that line on the config.xml on the root of your project and it will be copied

Comment: thanks ;) @jcesarmobile